Using Google service account key getting error of Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority
How can I resolve the "Service accounts cannot invite attendees without Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority" error when using a Google service account key to create an event in Google Calendar?
I am trying to authenticate and create a scheduled interview event using a Google service account key, but I am encountering the following error:
{
"code": 500,
"message": "Service accounts cannot invite attendees without Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority."
}
Here are the steps I have taken so far:

Added all the necessary Google Calendar scopes in the Manage Domain-Wide Delegation section, including:


https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.addons.execute

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.settings.readonly

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events.readonly

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive



Enabled the Google Calendar API in my Google Cloud Console for the project associated with my service account.

Previously, I was using the googleapi npm package, which was working fine for single event scheduling. However, now I am trying to schedule multiple interviews at once, which resulted in multiple authentication popups with the old code. To avoid these popups, I switched to using a service account.
Despite these configurations, I am still facing the error. What am I missing, or what additional steps do I need to take to enable the service account to invite attendees to the event?
I have also verified my code and had it reviewed by some SSEs and there is no issue with the code also In the Console the msg is
code: 403,
errors: [
{
domain: 'calendar',
reason: 'forbiddenForServiceAccounts',
message: 'Service accounts cannot invite attendees without Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority.'
}
]

as you mention after enabling all the Domain Wide Delegation settings for the service account you have to impersonate a user to invite the attendees
here is more information about making delegated requests with a service accounthttps://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#delegatingauthority
I hope this is helpful for you
